# socket.error: port/proto not found

Tags: python, oracle, sockets

I'm trying to get the service name of port number 1521 using socket package. 
This is the code I'm trying to execute in shell

```
import socket
portname = socket.getservbyport(1521)
print portname
```

The error I'm getting is as below

> ```
> portname = socket.getservbyport(i)
> socket.error: port/proto not found
> ```

If I'm using any other port such as 22,80,1433,3306 their isn't any problem in retrieving the port/service name. 
I've tried similar code on two other Linux Machine but their isn't any response.

Comment: Does your host computer have an advertised service listening on port 1521?

Comment: By "advertised", I mean it is listed in `/etc/services`.

Comment: No it isn't, and thanks @JohnGordon for your help. But if a server is using 1521 will it respond to a connect request.